# How to specify initSQL in Flyways command line tool?

Tags: flyway

Flyway's Java API provides capability to specify SQL statements which are executed right after the connection to the target database was established (via Flyway.setDatasource => [javadoc](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/api/javadoc/org/flywaydb/core/Flyway.html#setDataSource-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String...-)). A typical use case for such SQLs is session initialization.

```
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();

// datasource with initilization SQL 
flyway.setDataSource(url, user, password, initSQL);

flyway.setLocations("sql/migrations");
flyway.migrate();
```

I'm wondering if there isn't a similar functionality in Flyway's command line tool. I've already browsed official documentation ressources available at https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/ but I did not find a way to accomplish this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not supported yet. Please file a feature request in the Flyway issue tracker.

Comment: Axel, thanks for this feedback. I created feature request [#1324](https://github.com/flyway/flyway/issues/1324) in the Flyway issue tracker.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to have Flyway execute scripts from within your java application the starting point is as simple as the following example code

```
Flyway flyway = new Flyway();

// Set the data source
flyway.setDataSource(dataSource);

// Where to search for classes to be executed or SQL scripts to be found
flyway.setLocations("net.somewhere.flyway");

flyway.setTarget(MigrationVersion.LATEST);
flyway.migrate();
```

The starting point in the documentation is here

```
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/migration/java
```

Comment: Well, thanks for that comment but I was actually asking about Flyway's command line tool, not the Flyway Java API. I need to initialize the database session (e.g. ALTER SESSION set ...) which is used by Flyway to apply the migrations...

Comment: LOL, then it may not have been a good idea to link to Java docs :) I'll try and answers this in another answer.

Answer (score 0):

The original poster has expressed what they are trying to do in a comment to another answer.

The part of the manual you need to start from can be found here

https://flywaydb.org/documentation/commandline/

This details how to create the config file that will provide the command line version of Flyway the correct database connection details to allow it to run migration scripts.

It is not clear why you need to be able to use DDL statements such as ALTER SESSION once Flyway has a connection as the connection should have been created with the correct schema having been defined. Changing the schema once connected will cause Flyway issues as it defines a table in which it tracks changes per schema. So if you wish to make changes to a number of schemas there are strategies listed in the FAQ under the title "Does Flyway support multiple schemas?"

```
https://flywaydb.org/documentation/faq
```

Comment: It's clear how to provide Flyway parameters to create the database connection. The question was regarding a feature which is available when using Flyway with the Java API, but obviously not when using Flyway with the command line tool. I guess my original question was not clear enough that's why why I edited the original post. Sry for the confusion ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I also was looking for something like initial sql for command line flyway.
In my case I needed to do

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE= 'ENGLISH';
```

As I work from Poland and started to receive ORA errors in polish , which is not my native language:)
And I decided to share it here as it might be useful because it always show error messages in local language.

error message before (in Polish)

### Migration V-1.0.0.27__add stg_trading_book_seq .sql failed

SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 955
Message    : ORA-00955: nazwa jest już używana przez istniejący obiekt

after

### Migration V-1.0.0.27__add stg_trading_book_seq .sql failed

SQL State  : 42000
Error Code : 955
Message    : ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object

So what helped for me 
I put  JVM parameter -Duser.language=en   to flyway.cmd (for linux just flyway) in root flyway folder

```
%JAVA_CMD% -cp "%INSTALLDIR%\lib\*;%INSTALLDIR%\drivers\*" -Duser.language=en org.flywaydb.commandline.Main %*
```